# How to best use 'this' when its unavailable

Tags: javascript, events, oop, this

say I create `someObj` like this

```
var someObj = function(){
  var self = this;
  //use this normally
  document.body.addEventListener('click',function(){
     //use self because this is unavailable
  },false)
}
new someObj();
```

In the event `this` is not the `someObj` which id like to use but in this case the body element. Is there a best practice way to get `someObj` or is declaring some `self` var like in the example considered any good?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `self` seems fine to me.
You might also want to check out using `call` or `apply` (see for example [odetocode](http://odetocode.com/Blogs/scott/archive/2007/07/05/function-apply-and-function-call-in-javascript.aspx) and specifically about `this` in this [post](http://odetocode.com/Blogs/scott/archive/2007/07/06/putting-function-apply-to-work.aspx))

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, declaring something like 'self' is the easiest way to do it.

I would consider your code to be perfectly acceptable.